# How to get ordered product image from getAllVisibleItems()

Tags: magento2, orders, product-images

I have to display an image of the ordered product.
I am using `getAllVisibleItems()` to get all the details of my order.

From where I can get my ordered product image.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method:

Get the sku of the item as below

```
$dataHelper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {  
$sku = $item->getSku();
$image = $dataHelper->getProductImageUrl($sku);
}
```

Your helper class  `Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,

        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
        )
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getProductBySku($sku) {
        return $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    }
    public function getProductImageUrl($sku) {
        $image_url = '';
        $product = $this->getProductBySku($sku);

        if (isset($product)) {
           $image_url = $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium')->setImageFile($product->getImage())->resize(480, 600)->getUrl();
        } 
        return $image_url;
    }
}
```